# How extract vocabulary vectors from gensim's word2vec?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec, text-classification

I want to analyze the vectors looking for patterns and stuff, and use SVM on them to complete a classification task between class A and B, the task should be supervised. (I know it may sound odd but it's our homework.) so as a result I really need to know:

1- how to extract the coded vectors of a document using a trained model?

2- how to interpret them and how does word2vec code them?

I'm using gensim's word2vec.

Comment: If you are trying to categorize whole documents, you should check Doc2Vec model which is also available in gensim library. The (little bit outdated) tutorial is here: https://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/ and be sure to check my answer here with up-to-date version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321209/doc2vec-how-to-get-document-vectors/39329194#39329194

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have trained word2vec model, you can get word-vector by `__getitem__` method

   `model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)
   print(model["some_word_from_dictionary"])`
2. Unfortunately, embeddings from word2vec/doc2vec not interpreted by a person (in contrast to topic vectors from LdaModel)

P/S If you have texts at the object in your tasks, then you should use Doc2Vec model