# What does epochs mean in Doc2Vec and train when I have to manually run the iteration?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to understand the `epochs` parameter in the `Doc2Vec` function and `epochs` parameter in the `train` function.

In the following code snippet, I manually set up a loop of 4000 iterations. Is it required or passing 4000 as epochs parameter in the Doc2Vec enough? Also how `epochs` in `Doc2Vec` is different from epochs in `train`?

```
documents = Documents(train_set)

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, dbow_words=1, dm=0, epochs=4000,  window=5,
                seed=1337, min_count=5, workers=4, alpha=0.001, min_alpha=0.025)

model.build_vocab(documents)

for epoch in range(model.epochs):
    print("epoch "+str(epoch))
    model.train(documents, total_examples=total_length, epochs=1)
    ckpnt = model_name+"_epoch_"+str(epoch)
    model.save(ckpnt)
    print("Saving {}".format(ckpnt))
```

Also, how and when are the weights updated?

Comment: @Downvoter It is so frustrating to have a downvote without a comment on how to improve the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to manually run the iteration, and you *shouldn't* call `train()` more than once unless you're an expert who needs to do so for very specific reasons. If you've seen this technique in some online example you're copying, that example is likely outdated and misleading.

Call `train()` once, with your preferred number of passes as the `epochs` parameter.

Also, don't use a starting `alpha` learning-rate that is low (`0.001`) that then rises to a `min_alpha` value 25 times larger (`0.025`) - that's not how this is supposed to work, and most users shouldn't need to adjust the `alpha`-related defaults at all. (Again, if you're getting this from an online example somewhere - that's a bad example. Let them know they're giving bad advice.)

Also, 4000 training epochs is absurdly large. A value of 10-20 is common in published work, when dealing with tens-of-thousands to millions of documents. If your dataset is smaller, it may not work well with `Doc2Vec`, but sometimes more epochs (or smaller `vector_size`) can still learn something generalizable from tiny data - but still expect to use closer to dozens of epochs (not thousands).

A good intro (albeit with a tiny dataset that barely works with `Doc2Vec`) is the `doc2vec-lee.ipynb` Jupyter notebook that's bundled with gensim, and also viewable online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb

Good luck!

Comment: Okay. When would one need to call `train` more than once?

Comment: An advanced user who needed to do some mid-training logging or analysis or adjustment might split the training over multiple `train()` calls, and very consciously manage the effective `alpha` parameters for each call. An extremely advanced user experimenting with further training on an already-trained model might also try it, aware of all of the murky quality/balance issues that might involve. But essentially, unless you already know specifically why you'd need to do so, and the benefits and risks, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Could you also explain the parameter `vector_size`? How to decide the value of this attribute?

Comment: It's the size in dimensions of the word-vectors/doc-vectors that are created, and typical values range from 100 (the gensim default, for speed and memory-compactness) to 1000. Values of 300-400 seem especially common for word-vectors. The only way to know what's best for your data/goal is to search over different values, using a rigorous repeatable evaluation to score each option. Larger values will only make sense if you have a *lot* of data, and RAM, and time to train. (If working on toy-sized examples of a few hundred or few thousand texts, even 100-dimensions may be too much.)